# how to mock private variable in RestController class

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am doing some web unit testing with Spring. is there a way I can mock the instance of `MyProcessor` which get set in `@PostConstruct`? I tried with `@MockBean` but it gets set as null and getting null pointer exception?

I am using a factory to instantiate `MyProcessor` based on some boolean flag. But if there is a different approach altogether that would make my test cleaner, I am open to ideas.

Please Note I am using Junit 5.

```
public class Controller {

    private final AProcessorFactory factory;

    @Value("${tt.f.processor.async}")
    private boolean isAsync;

    private MyProcessor myProcessor;

    public Controller(final AProcessorFactory factory) {
        this.factory= factory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        myProcessor = factory.getInstance(isAsync);
    }

}


@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest{

    @MockBean
    private MyProcessor processor;


    @MockBean
    private AProcessorFactory factory;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {           

        when(processor.process(any(Request.class), any(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(new TestResponse("123", SUCCESS, "", ""));

}
```

Comment: refactoring your class to use constructor injection would help improve the testability of your code. the PostConstruct would make it difficult to have JUnit aware of this injection.

Comment: set that flag in constructor a swll

Comment: how would I then mock/set this in my test class. Both async flag and the MyProcessor instance

Comment: @shinjw - with junit5 and constructor injection, how would it look? can you provide one example

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `myProcessor` is actually built by your `AProcessorFactory` in a PostConstruct init() method.

You'll want to provide a behavior for your `AProcessorFactory` mock.

First, you would probably want to set up your `myProcessor` in your constructor as the `@PostConstruct` `init()` method has no special context loading logic with it.

```
public class Controller {

    @Value("${tt.f.processor.async}")
    private boolean isAsync;

    private MyProcessor myProcessor;

    public Controller(final AProcessorFactory factory) {
        this.myProcessor = factory.getInstance(isAsync);
    }
}
```

You can specify this in a `@Before` step in your test.

```
 @MockBean
 private AProcessorFactory factory;

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
     when(processor.process(any(Request.class), any(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(new TestResponse("123", SUCCESS, "", ""));
     when(factory.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(processor)
 }
```

Spring will register your AProcessorFactory mock that has been loaded with the appropriate behaviors.

Comment: How will this look with Junit5? @BeforeAll would work with PostConstruct?

Comment: Just in the Before step would be appropriate.